# What is this character? �

Tags: c#, string, character-encoding

I have some text coming from a feed as shown below with this unusual character:

The new Siri voice controlled assistant lets you use your voice to send messages, schedule meetings, place phone calls and much more. Siri understands what you say, knows what you mean, and even talks back. For example you could say something like �Tell my wife I�m running late�, �Remind me to call the vet�, or �What's the weather like for tomorrow?� And Siri will answer.

What is it and how do I get rid of it? I can't do a replace as I'm not sure what it actually is.

Thanks

Comment: You're not decoding the feed with the same character-set it is encoded with...

Answer (score 6):

This is a replacement character displayed instead of characters that can't be displayed by the current encoding.

Try to switch your encoding to the one used by the source feed.

Comment: so the right answer should be to use the same encoding as the message is encoded in

Answer (score 3):

The character “�” is U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, which indicates character-level data error. Reference: The Unicode Standard, [ch. 16](http://www.unicode.org/versions/latest/ch16.pdf), clause 16.8.

Nowadays it most often appears to indicate that some data contains bytes that have no meaning in the character encoding being applied. So it signals absence of valid character data, rather than just somehow incorrect or undisplayable character.

A typical situation is that Latin 1 encoded data is being interpreted as UTF-8 encoded. In your example, it seems that all non-Ascii characters, such as “smart” quotes, apostrophes, and perhaps en dashes have turned to “�”. It is quite possible that the data itself is correct; it is just the information about its encoding that is wrong. If the encoding (according to which the data is interpreted) can be changed in program settings, trying UTF-8 probably helps.

The character “�” may also appear when data has been converted from one encoding to another and there is a character in the data that has no representation in the target encoding. In this case, the original data would have been lost, and one would need to make guesses or get back to the original encoded data to restore the information.

Answer (score 2):

It's because  you don't have the correct encoding - here's a great read which goes into more detail:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html